# The Gemara (Sukkah 25b) mentions "taking your mind off your worries." Do any commentators elaborate on exactly how to do that?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mussar-ethics, agada-stories-legends, kavana-intent, masechet-sukkah

The Gemara (**[Sukkah 25b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.25b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)**) mentions that an *avel* (mourner) is obligated in the mitzvah of Sukkah. One might have thought that since someone who is *mitzta'er* (in pain) is exempt from the mitzvah, that an *avel*, due to his emotional pain, would also be exempt.

The Gemara concludes that, since his worries are "*divrei reshus*" (not obligatory, in contrast to someone who is worried about performing a mitzvah properly), that he should be able to take his mind off it -- achieve *yishuv ha'daas* -- and focus on the mitzvah of sukkah.

I've looked around in some standard commentaries of aggadah hoping to find details about how a person should actually accomplish this *yishuv ha'daas*. I've looked in the commentaries of the Ein Yaakov, in B'Nei Yehoyada, and the Maharal. I've also checked out the index of Alei Shur and Michtav M'eliyahu for any references to this Gemara, but found none.

Do you know of any sources that do elaborate on this?

Comment: I assume it means focus on the task at hand, the way a mourner would do for any necessity.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pYCYXtd9sE
Sorry no textual sources, but sof kol sof the point is you can't stop thinking, but you can always change subject, and the best way to achieve this is to have another subject - even better, a memorized text such as mishnayot - that you can switch to for half an hour or so, which can uproot the old subject from your mind completely

Comment: "_The Gemara concludes that, since his worries are 'divrei reshus' (not obligatory, in contrast to someone who is worried about performing a mitzvah properly)_". From the translation and commentary (that @Dov linked to in his revision of the question), it seems that the conclusion is that only one who is _mitzta'er_ from performing the mitzvah of Sukkah is exempt from it, not anyone who is _mitzta'er_ for any reason. (1) Where do you get what you said from? (2) Who uses the term "_divrei reshus_" (דברי רשות) in [regards to] Sukkah 25b?

Comment: Dr. Pelcovitz talks about the Gemara with two opinions -- *yischena milibo* or *yesichena le'acherim* -- and that people are usual on a spectrum of avoidant vs. attendant. Depends on the person which one is the right strategy! (In some cases, distraction is good.) Obviously, sometimes the answer is a good one-on-one sitdown with a rabbi, and potentially a mental-health professional.

Comment: Grab your coat and get your hat.
Leave your worry on the doorstep.
Just direct your feet
To the sunny side of the street.

Can't you hear a pitter-pat?
And that happy tune is your step.
Life can be so sweet
On the sunny side of the street.

I used to walk in the shade
With those blues on parade,
But now I'm not afraid.
This rover crossed over. 

Answer (score 0):

Avel can reach  yesuvai daas through kavnas halev.
חדושי הר"ן על מועד קטן דף כא ע/א
'ואמרו המפרשים ז"ל דמיבעי ליה לאבל ליתובי דעתיה ולכווני ליבא לתפילין שלא יסיח דעתו מהם כדמוכח במס'
יומא (ז' ב')
And dont try to say tefillin is different b/c you cant be maisiach daas b/c magen avrohom equates sukkah and tefillin.
ספר מגן אברהם על או"ח סימן לח:
(ו) פנים חדשות. פירוש מנחמים חדשים וא"ת למה חייב אבל בתפילין הא אמרי' לקמן מצטער פטור מתפילין י"ל ה"מ
צערא דממילא אבל הכא איהו דקמצער נפשיה איבעיא ליה ליתובי דעתיה כדאמרינן בסוכה פ"ב לענין

Comment: Hi @user31723 - welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please can you make your answers more user friendly. There are many users who can't read Hebrew let alone understand it. If you bring a quote, please either summarise it or provide translations. Wishing you much hatzlocho.